# __kernel_vsyscall in assembly function (gdb)

Tags: c, malloc, sigabrt, gnu-assembler, att

I have a __kernel_vsyscall error in a function that gives the correct output but the program can never get past it and gives a __kernel_vsyscall error.
C functions:

```
void f1(int* input, int* output, int nbElements);
```

Assembler function (GAS). I can't post the whole thing since it's for an assignment and I don't want someone to copy it.

```
f1:
    push %ebp
    mov %esp, %ebp

    movl $0, %ecx
    movl $0, %ebx

    jmp for_loop1

for_loop1:

    cmpl %ecx, 16(%ebp)
    jb end
    movl $0, %ebx
    jmp for_loop2

for_loop2:
    /*move input elements to output elements*/
    cmpl %ecx, %ebx
    jmp incr_2

incr_2:

    addl $1, %ebx
    cmpl %ebx, 16(%ebp)
    jb incr_1
    jmp for_loop2

incr_1:
    addl $1, %ecx
    jmp for_loop1

end:        
    addl $8, %esp               
    leave
    ret
```

Error when the program terminated :

```
malloc(): invalid size (unsorted)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Error when debugging with gdb with the coredump file :

```
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./program_name...
[New LWP 2634]

warning: Loadable section ".note.gnu.property" outside of ELF segments
Core was generated by `./program_name'.
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
#0  0xf7f35ac9 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
```

I've tried looking at what is at address 0xf7f35ac9 and it returned -402652697, or another random value.

Local variables are at adresses around 0xff83b1fc, the values stored in the pointers are at adresses around 0x80cab30, the functions declared previously are at adresses around 0x8049fc4, and the stack has values around 0xffaddedc, so I have no idea where this is.

Thanks

Comment: `addl $8, %esp` doesn't look correct.  Your `push %ebp` is cleaned up by `leave`, and you haven't pushed anything else onto the stack or changed `%esp` in any other way, so this will mess things up.  The `ret` will then "return" to whatever address happens to be on the stack 8 bytes further up, which is surely not good and may account for your program ending up at a random address.

Comment: But the `malloc: invalid size` is almost surely the result of overflowing a buffer, or otherwise messing up access to a dynamically allocated buffer.  This function, as you've written it, doesn't do anything of the kind, so the bug must be elsewhere (or in some part of the function that you didn't post - can't help you with that).

Comment: Oh, and you need to save and restore `%ebx`.  But this function doesn't appear to actually do anything at all.  If you've edited it down, you've gone too far; we'd need a [mcve] that actually compiles (a full program!) and demonstrates the problem.  Please don't ask people to debug fake or incomplete code.

Comment: thanks for answering! for the value in the pointers, im supposed to copy ```input[0] to input[8]``` into ```output[0] to output[8]``` so the first for loop should run 3 times and the second for loop should run a total of 9 times

Comment: Yeah, but the code you've posted doesn't actually copy anything whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by changing

```
cmpl %ecx, 16(%ebp)
jb end
```

to

```
cmpl 16(%ebp), %ecx
jge end
```

same as with all the other comparisons. Looked around online and apparently the difference between jb/ja and jl/jg is that jb/ja is for unsigned comparison while jl/jg is for signed comparison, but I'm still not sure why this causes this error.